# Javascript "link" should not load

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, load, hyperlink

I know it sounds weird, but i need to make that…

So I have this function, that activates onClick.

`function opensite() { location.href='https://www.site.com/'; }`

Is there a way to open that url, but not load it?

So your browser will say something like "page not found/server down/no internet connection"…

Is it possible and how ? My server can use every language … (JS,JQUERY,PHP,HTML…)

Why I should do this ? Long story, please don't ask about ;)

Thank you

Evert

****EDIT****

I have a script that perfectly works without internet connection because it doesn't load the page in the 'link'… I'm trying to make this also work WITH internet connection...

Comment: what in the world ? - Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: So what you're actually asking is how to check if a given URL is reachable.

Comment: You don't want to show the content to anyone? or for any particular person?

Comment: What do you mean by *to open URL, but not load it*? Just change the address in the address bar or what?

Comment: @jAndy  Like i said, it opens the page but it doesn't load… It should just give a blank screen or an error… I KNOW IT'S STRANGE, BUT I NEED IT.

Comment: @VisioN yeah, something like that..

Comment: Hide the content then, from that page, using hide();

Comment: @Saswata I don't want to hide the content… That's not the problem, it should not load…if that's possible

Comment: I thought this page would explain a tutorial as your question title says. Always give a title that is search friendly to others so that no one have to solve one problem twice.  But also your question isnt clear. Make it readable to us. Thanks

Comment: It's doable if you check on the server if the page is available. If it isn't, redirect to it. If it is, redirect to yoursite.com/blank.html that shows a blank page. If you want the address bar to show the new URL but not its contents, it's not possible (unless it's a site you control).

Comment: @Juhana Yes, that's what i wanted… ok.. thx

Comment: I have a script that perfectly works without internet connection because it doesn't load the page in the 'link'… I'm trying to make this also work WITH internet connection...

Answer (score 0):

If you own the site you are trying to make appear offline, then the easiest way is to upload an index.html containing the error you are trying to display.

But really, no. This is not possible.

I am assuming you do not own the other site, and due to security reasons, browsers block this type of behavior. Since you are asking to bypass security settings, and telling us "don't ask" I can only assume you are trying to steal peoples identities.

No matter how bad you need this to work, it wont. Stop trying.

Edit:

If you simply do not want your website to follow a click, then I would use `e.preventDefault()` in your jQuery event handler

Comment: I have a script that perfectly works without internet connection because it doesn't load the page in the 'link'… I'm trying to make this also work WITH internet connection...

Comment: Why are you developing a script that is designed not to work? Can you please explain why they would click something with the intent of it not to work?

Comment: It's a hack… They are not gonna see that error page, but it must be there to make it work… When i have internet connection, there is no error, and then you just go to that page AND THATS THE PROBLEM

Comment: Sounds like you need to hire a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
window.open('http://www.site.com/')
```

But some browser will block the pop-up window. There's also another way:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://www.site.com/';
a.target = '_blank';
a.click();
```

to emulate a click on a link.